# Finding acceleration only with known acceleration distance, final velocity, and mass for Newton's Third Law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

So I have this problem that I am trying to figure out. 
I need to find the acceleration of a 4 kg object, that is accelerated through a distance of 1 m to the left to a final velocity of 6 m/s. This does not seem possible without knowing any times??

I know a = (vf-vi)/t
d = 0.5at^2
a = fnet/m

None of them seem to work with the given data.

It is the third law because a person on a frictionless surface throws the object to the left.

Comment: Was the object accelerated from rest? If so, you can set $v_0=0$ and solve the problem.

Comment: yes it was accelerated from zero m/s

Comment: @HDE226868, but I still do not know the time. If I use s = d/t, then time is 1/6 s?

Comment: when I solve for time using Vf and t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's what you do:**
You know $v_0$, $v_f$, and $x$. This means you can use the equation
$$v_f^2=v_0^2+2ax$$
Re-arrange it to get
$$a=\frac{v_f^2-v_0^2}{2x}$$
You also know the mass, $m$. You can use Newton' second law, $F=ma$, here:
$$F=m\frac{v_f^2-v_0^2}{2x}$$
This should lead you to the answer.